# How to set save location to 'CURRENT' GDB in ArcGIS Pro Tasks

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-path, dynamic, tasks, working-directory

I'm new to authoring tasks, and now that I'm attempting to use my task in a second project, the saves are being directed to the GDB I was in when I created the Task.
How can I dynamically assign save location to my working directory instead? Is there something similar to the following that I can tack in front of the Output Features filename?

G:(Directory)\New Location\%CURRENT%\%CURRENT%.gdb\(filename)

[image: Task window]

Answer (score 3):

Geoprocessing environmental settings can be set or altered in several places in ArcGIS including the tool itself, in scripts, in Modelbuilder, or system wide.  [See this link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/what-is-a-geoprocessing-environment.htm) for more information on environmental setting hierarchies.

Comment: If I get your drift you're saying the tool workspace is overriding the project workspace?
I'm not seeing how that gets at how to call the current workspace into my output filepath.